# Which files do i need to include to perform database query?

Tags: database, jdatabase

I am trying to practice Joomla database query. For learning purpose, I'd like to know in a blank PHP file under Joomla's root folder, which files do I need to include to be able to do

```
$db = JFactory::getDbo();
$query = $db->getQuery(true);
```

Answer (score 2):

You will need to load the Joomla framework at the top of the PHP file, like so:

```
<?php

define('_JEXEC', 1);
define('JPATH_BASE', './'); // Assumes the PHP file is in the Joomla's root directory
require_once JPATH_BASE . 'includes/defines.php';
require_once JPATH_BASE . 'includes/framework.php';
```

You can then write your database query, for example, to load all the data from the `#__users` table:

```
<?php

define('_JEXEC', 1);
define('JPATH_BASE', './');
require_once JPATH_BASE . 'includes/defines.php';
require_once JPATH_BASE . 'includes/framework.php';

use Joomla\CMS\Factory;

$db = Factory::getDbo();
$db->setQuery(
    $db->getQuery(true)
        ->select('*')
        ->from($db->qn('#__users'))
);
$users = $db->loadObjectList();

var_dump($users);
```